# To fetch column name

Tags: mysql, hibernate, struts2

I am using struts2 , hibernate and MySql for my project.
I have table name TimeTable having 42 columns (all long datatype) containing course codes.
I want to search "column names" having particular course code from a particular row.
Help me please.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Are the table column names the names of the courses? Are the column values the course codes? If you find a course code you want to get the name of the column it is in?

Comment: i want to know "table Column Name".column names are like Monday_Session_1 and so on. Now i have a value i.e. course code.Each column stores course code.Now i want to search "table column name" whose value matches with course code i have.

Answer (score 1):

If you have mapped the entity in a "proper" way in hibernate, the answer is obvious:

You will have an entity called TimeTable, which have 42 relationships to Course (I bet the attribute name will be course1, course2.... course42).

The resulting HQL is simply a bunch of OR

```
from TimeTable t
where t.course1.code = :something 
  OR t.course2.code = :something .....
```

However, it is obviously a bad model design.  You should make Timetable and Course a Many-To-Many relationship, and have another table storing the relationship.  So, in the entity, you will see something like

```
class TimeTable {
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Course> courses;
}
```

Your life will be much easier with such design.

Comment: thank you!  i have to change my design or is there any other solution possible.

Comment: The solution is in the answer: having a bunch of OR statements.  However, I think spending time in changing the design to a more appropriate one, is much more valuable than spending time finding workarounds for that design.  (Unless there is no way you can change the design)